# Accessing file in home directory from apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

After searching a lot I am asking my question here. I have an image file in my `/home/uploads/images/filename.jpg` which I am tryin to access in browser like `http://www.example.com/~uploads/images/filename.jpg`. But it is not working.

Similarly I have another image file in `/var/www/html/images/filename.jpg` which I can access in browser as `http://www.example.com/images/filename.jpg`.

Why am I not able to access it from /home ? I have given all permission to it.

Answer (score 0):

apache traditionally converts urls with a tilde (~) like

```
http://www.example.com/~uploads/images/filename.jpg
```

to the filename `/home/uploads/public_html/images/filename.jpg`.  You need
to find in one of the apache config files a line defining `UserDir` and change
it from `disabled` to

```
UserDir public_html
```

You will also need to find a paragraph beginning

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/>
```

and ensure it is not commented out (with `#` at start of lines).